# How do I NOT prevent a device from being eject/safely removed?

Tags: c, file, winapi, device

#### How do I get a `HANDLE` to a file* on some device, and *not* prevent the user from ejecting the device?

I've tried calling `CreateFile` (and even `NtCreateFile`) with the most liberal access I can think of -- i.e. `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` for access, and `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE` for sharing permissions, but it still doesn't work.

([FileTest](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=360) is a great tool for testing this, without writing a program.)

---

#### *Update:

I'd *really* love the solution to work for handles to *volumes* or *drives* as well (not just files) -- I mean like `\\.\D:` or `\\.\PhysicalDrive0`. But if there's no such solution, then handles to files would also be useful.

Comment: I suspect that it's not possible. The user probably has to do a forced dismount before they can eject.

Comment: @Gabe: Dismount of what, though? As far as I know, `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` doesn't even bother mounting the file system if it's not already mounted.

Comment: This will not be possible. what use of handle once device is ejected?

Comment: @Rohan: I don't buy that reasoning. If you can delete a file whose only handles have `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` sharing mode, why can't you eject its device?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your response. Are you saying that you can get a handle to a file on a filesystem that hasn't been mounted?

Comment: @Gabe: Ah, sorry. I didn't mean a file, but the volume itself -- like `\\.\X:`. (The problem I'm referring to is the same for files, volumes, and disks alike.)

Comment: @Mehrdad Even if handle has FILE_SHARE_DELETE, file is still open and has valid handle, which I think will cause not to unmount that drive.

Comment: @Rohan: Sure... though I don't understand what your point is. (Is this a continuation of our previous conversation above?)

Comment: @Mehrdad, yes, I'm trying to explain my point. Sorry if its out of context.

Comment: @Rohan: Sorry, I don't follow your reasoning. You said (I'm paraphrasing), "Wouldn't a file handle be useless if you could eject the device the file is on?" and I told you "That reasoning doesn't make sense to me, because you can say the same thing about a deleted file, and yet handles with FILE_SHARE_DELETE allow the files to be deleted." You responded by saying "FILE_SHARE_DELETE doesn't let you unmount the file's drive", which looks like it's just repeating the observation I'd already made in my post. So sorry, I'm quite confused... how is your comment related to my response?

Comment: Perhaps you can solve your original problem differently. E.g., do you really need to keep that file handle, or would it suffice to get it only when you need it and free it again immediately, so the file is "locked" only for a very short time? If you can go into detail as to your ultimate goal, perhaps we'll find a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

It should be clear that obtaining a file handle while a volume is mounted is trivial.

What happens when the volume is forcibly dismounted?  All file handles become invalid.  Attempts to use them return errors.

These code snippets forcibly dismounts a volume so that subsequent code can do direct i/o on it.  This is excerpted from a disk cleaner utility (a mass consumer product) I wrote a few years back.

```
char    fn [20];

sprintf (fn, "\\\\.\\%s:", vol -> GetVolName ());
vol_lock_handle = CreateFile (fn, GENERIC_READ,
                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS,
                NULL);

fprintf (stderr,
 "Warning:  volume dismount will disrupt or kill all processes with open files!\n"
 "Before confirming, verify no critical processes have open files on volume %s:\n"
 "   Are you sure you want to dismount this volume? ('YES' to proceed)? ",
         g_vol -> GetVolName ());

char    buf [30];
if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)  ||  stricmp (buf, "yes\n"))
{
    fprintf (stderr, " Volume dismount not confirmed--canceled.\n");
    continue;
}
DWORD   status;
if (!DeviceIoControl (vol_lock_handle, FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME,
                        NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &status, NULL))
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError ();
    fprintf (stderr, "Error %d attempting to dismount volume: %s\n",
            err, w32errtxt (err));
}
```

I am perfectly aware of how wrong this code looks.  A GENERIC_READ handle is obtained for dismounting, then obtaining a volume lock, and then written to.  It works!

Comment: Is the handle usable after the volume has been dismounted?

Comment: @Mehrdad:  Yes, for locking and unlocking, and reading and writing the volume.  The files are not accessible without parsing the volume (which is something else my utility did).

Comment: So that means the user can't continue using the volume at all? :( The goal (although I guess I didn't say it explicitly..) was to prevent disrupting the user's work. :\

Comment: @Mehrdad:  That is correct.  How do you expect a process to read or write to a volume which is dismounted?

Comment: Uh, right... but then your solution is worse than the problem! It's as if I had asked "How do I rent a room in your apartment?" and your solution was "Evict everyone else!" :P (Also, note that my original question had asked for a handle to a **file** on a device, but this is a handle to a volume, not a file.)

Comment: @Mehrdad:  I can understand why you might think my code is worse than the posed problem.  In short, what you are asking for is a) nonsensical, b) impractical, and c) impossible.  Perhaps if I made that my answer you would like it better?  I show what *is* possible, including the explanatory text of what happens when the volume is forcibly dismounted.

Comment: Well I mean, it's not that I *think* it's worse, it's that it *is* worse (it's useless for me, since if I'm going to disrupt the user then I might as well have him kill my own app instead). I could understand (b) and (c), but would you mind explaining (a) (why you think it's "nonsensical")?

Comment: @Mehrdad:  It is nonsensical to get a handle to a file *while* allowing them to eject the media.  Would that mean before, during, or after ejection?  "Before" makes good sense, but "while" is hard to grok.  Possibly you mean "get a file hand *and* allow media eject"?  What would you do with a handle of file on missing media?  I can't imagine what use that would be&mash;unless you except Windows to cache and buffer until the media is returned.  (A media IOU?  :-)

Comment: LOL, yes, I definitely meant *"and"*, although I'm pretty sure my question has the exact same meaning as-is. :) (When I wrote "...while allowing them..", I was hoping it would be read as though it was "... while *still* allowing them...")

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

But what you can do is to watch for the eject device message and then close all the handles you have.

[Device Events (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 this might be just as good of a solution for my situation! :)